# How to use JSON data from a url in order to set markers in a map activity android

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps

Hello I am new to android and I wanted to know how can I get JSON data from a url and then use that data from the URL to set markers in an android map activity.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Reading the json? Google's [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) may help you.

Comment: And to read GeoJSON you can use [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/#introduction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `HttpUrlConnection` to get the JSON data, and then create a new `JSONObject`  object using the JSON `data` you got from the server (url), now you have just to get the information from the `JSONObject` by respecting the keys the url provide. at this point you need just to pass the values to `GoogleMap` Object. for example:

let's supppose that the url respond with this JSON data:

```
{ 
   "long" : 25,
   "lat" : 6
}
```

you recover the code by using an `HttpURLConnection` :

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost_or_any_url/mypage.php");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
String buff = "", data= "";
InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
while ((buff = br.readLine()) != null) data+= buff;
JSONObject json= new JSONObject(data);
int long= json.getInt("long");
int lat= json.getInt("lat");
```

now you have your location (x,y) (longitude, latitude) on the two variables (long, lat), you just have to pass them to your `GoogleMap` object to create a marker like this :

```
LatLng myPosition= new LatLng(-34, 151);
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title("My position"));
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPosition));
//the last line (the call to moveCamera method) is optional, it helps to move the camera to the marker in case the current map position is far from the marked position
```

this is a simple example, you need to be aware to where you get the data from the url (network operations cannot be performed inside the main Thread, you have to create an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread`) and how to pass the data to the class that holds the `GoogleMap` Object.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To get data from a URL you should do it in the background. There are various ways to do that, the easiest way may be creating a class that extends `AsyncTask` and using its `doInBackground` method. Here is some documentation about it.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Here you have an explanation of how to fetch data using `AsyncTask`.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

To parse JSON data, you can use the `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` classes. You basically have to instantiate a `JSONObject` with the JSON string as the argument of the constructor and then you use its methods `getJSONObject` and `getJSONArray` using the name of the data member you want to get. Here are the documentation about them and a tutorial. http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm

In the case the JSON string is compressed, to visualize the JSON string properly I suggest you to type it into https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com and then you can see it nicely formatted to see how the JSON is composed.

To call google maps, you use implicit intents, here is an Android tutorial of how to use them to use the main apps including google maps.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html